# How to use a SQL query "in" linq?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, linq

I have a SQL query like this:

```sql
 SELECT [Id],[WfInstanceId]
   FROM [WfTask]
  WHERE DocId IN 
        (SELECT [Id]
           FROM [FormInstance]
          WHERE FormId = '91889C15-7205-4467-B626-3C4AAB22567B')
```

How can I use it with linq? I want to return an IQueryable and pass it to my grid view.

Comment: Any() will generalize and you can check after giving the expression in the same.

Comment: Are use asking how to *translate* this SQL into a LINQ query or how to execute native SQL queries in Entity Framework (or Linq-To-Sql)?

Comment: chiccodoro im asking how to translate

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var q = from row in WfTast
        where (from x in FormInstance
               where FormId='91889C15-7205-4467-B626-3C4AAB22567B' &&
               row.DocId = id
               select x).Any()
        select Id, WfInstanceId;
```

Or, with join:

```
var q = from Task in WfTast
        join Form in (FormInstance.Where(x => x.FormId='91889C15-7205-4467-B626-3C4AAB22567B')
        on Task.DocId = Form.Id
        select Task.Id, Task.WfInstanceId;
```

or, Only flunet syntax:

```
var q = WfTast.Where(wt => FormInstance.Where(x => x.FormId='91889C15-7205-4467-B626-3C4AAB22567B' &&
                                                   wt.DocId = x.id).Any());
```

or:

```
var formsIdCollection =  FormInstance.Where(x => x.FormId='91889C15-7205-4467-B626-3C4AAB22567B').Select(x => x.id); 
// if you reuse this list, add at end this: .ToArray();

var q = from row in WfTast
        where formsIdCollection.Contains(row.DocId)
        select Id, WfInstanceId;
```

Comment: Thank you It's Great .it's what Im looking For ;)

Answer (score 0):

```
var query = DatabaseContext.WfTask.Where(
                i => DatabaseContext.FormInstane
                    .Where(fi => fi.FormId = '...')
                    .Select(fi => fi.Id)
                    .Contains(i.DocId));
```